# C# Linq: check if two datetime values are between two other datetime values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where a filter has a `fromDate` and `toDate`, showing objects that have a `startDate` and an `endDate`.

I woud like to use linq to check if the period between `startDate` and `endDate` is within `startDate` and `endDate` for the objects.

If fromDate is 10.10.2022 00:00 and toDate is 20.10.2022 00:00 (The filter)

Then following objects should be shown:

- startDate 09.10.2022 00:00 - endDate 11.10.2022 00:00 (Just within fromDate)
- startDate 11.10.2022 00:00 - endDate 15.10.2022 00:00 (Within fromDate and toDate)
- startDate 19.10.2022 00:00 - endDate 21.10.2022 00:00 (Just within toDate)

I can't seem to get it correct for all scenarios, any help appreciated.

Comment: "I can't seem to get it correct for all scenarios" - that sounds like you've already got some code and some tests... so please post that. (It would help if you'd clarify the requirements as well - your first and last examples are only *partially* within the bounds, so "the period between startDate and endDate is within startDate and endDate for the objects" doesn't sound quite right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
public bool Intersects(DateTime startDate1, DateTime endDate1, DateTime startDate2, DateTime endDate2)
{
    return (startDate2 > startDate1 && startDate2 < endDate1) ||
    (endDate2 > startDate1 && endDate2 < endDate1) ||
    (startDate2 < startDate1 && endDate2 > endDate1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates can overlap different ways

[image]